# How to name a Python dataframe column with two strings?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two strings say:

```
var1 = "abc"
var2 = "def"

# and now I want to create a new dataframe column called "abc_def". So I tried the following:
df[var1 + "_" + var2] = df['existing_col'].copy()
```

And then I get the error: `'str' object is not callable`

How can I resolve this? Thanks.

Comment: Works fine here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue with your code... it's working for me...

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"existing_col":[1,2,3]})
var1 = "abc"
var2 = "def"
df[var1 + "_" + var2] = df['existing_col'].copy()

# Output
   existing_col  abc_def
0             1        1
1             2        2
2             3        3
```